# Несколько запросов в рамках транзакции PHP->MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, транзакции

MySQL 5.7.25. БД с таблицами InnoDB.
Необходимо из PHP выполнить 3 запроса к БД в рамках одной транзакции. Т.е. либо все, либо ничего:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table1;
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (...);
UPDATE table2 SET col1=(SELECT c FROM table1 WHERE...);
```

Как правильнее поступить:

1) Использовать $mysqli->multi_query($db_query). И передать все три запроса в переменную $db_query?

2) каждый запрос выполнять отдельно $mysqli->query($db_query) и отслеживать каждый результат вывполения?

Если не трудно, приведите, пожалуйста, полный код с указанием начала транзации, подтверждения (commit) и отката при ошибке на любом этапе (rollback).
Какой код и логика обработки ошибок будут оптимальными?

Comment: Любой неудачный запрос должен вызывать исключение. Делаете блок `try catch`, в `try` начало, запросы и завершение транзакции. В `catch` откат транзакции и вызов исключения для обработки в коде выше. Всё можно оформить в метод, который принимает callback в качестве аргумента

Answer (score 2):

В упрощенном виде можно использовать такую схему:

```
$mysqli->query('START TRANSACTION');

try {
    if(false === $mysqli->query('TRUNCATE TABLE table1')) {
        throw new RuntimeException($mysqli->error);
    }
    if(false === $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (...)')) {
        throw new RuntimeException($mysqli->error);
    }
    if(false === $mysqli->query('UPDATE table2 SET col1=(SELECT c FROM table1 WHERE...)')) {
        throw new RuntimeException($mysqli->error);
    }
    if(false === $mysqli->query('COMMIT')) {
        throw new RuntimeException($mysqli->error);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $mysqli->query('ROLLBACK');
    echo $e->message;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю.  А с $mysqli->multi_query тоже самое можно сделать?

Comment: сложно, в multi_query _Возвращает FALSE, если *первое* выражение вызвало ошибку_ Придется все равно по отдельности дергать next_result

Comment: @Ruport забыл еще одну вещь указать. _Truncate operations cause an implicit commit, and so cannot be rolled back_ . Т.е `TRUNCATE` не транзакционная операция. Её нельзя отменить. Если не важен счетчик автоинкремента, то лучше использовать `DELETE FROM table1`

Comment: Для информации, https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting